# How can I properly airblast projectiles when around teammates?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-pyro

As a Pyro, I'm fine reflecting even fast-moving projectiles back at the shooter-- when I'm on my own. However, when one of my teammates is nearby, whenever I reflect an enemy projectile, regardless of where I reflect it, it flies up at a weird angle (I've only noticed this with rockets and grenades as I don't get much opportunity reflect other projectiles).

Is there a way I can prevent this, as it really weakens my strategy when, for example, a medic is pocketing me, and I'm trying to reflect kill a soldier and my reflected rocket flies in a random direction?

Comment: Is the air blast made as only a deflective thing? Maybe defending a teammate makes the projectiles uncontrollable?

Comment: Does this only happen if the teammate is in your sight? Say, potentially standing so that your crosshair is on their bounding box when you hit the button, or close enough that you're pushing each other? (If not then my theory is bunk.)

Comment: @Toomai Yes, it does. Only when my teammates are in front of me and in my line of sight.

Comment: As a Pyro whose primary damage output is in reflected projectiles, you have no idea how much this frustrates me every day. "I'm trying to protect you from enemy rockets, stop blocking me!" I end up getting myself killed instead.

Comment: @BoltClock I agree! It's more frustrating than throwing Mad Milk/Jarate at an enemy, and your teammate getting in the way and it splashing on your teammate.

Comment: Yeah, at least that is a feature. There is no sense in having a teammate block reflects whatsoever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**As of the 7 July 2016 update, this behaviour is supposed to be fixed; there should no longer be any difficulty with aiming reflections while near teammates.** The original answer follows.

---

Okay, I think I know what is happening here. This is basically a total guess, but it seems like the kind of thing that would happen in a Valve Source game.

Figure 1: A typical reflect. (I hid the rocket to see things better.)
[image: diagram of vectors during normal reflection]

Basically, the game checks where you're looking and directs the rocket that way.

Figure 2: A reflect with a taunting Scout in your face.
[image: reflection vectors with a teammate in close]

The teammate's axis-aligned world collision box is blocking your "vision", making the rocket's target point much closer to you, and so making it go a weird direction. It's just what happens when your targetting vector (your vision) isn't coming out of the same place the attack is: it happens at every range, you just don't really notice unless it's point-blank. The Wrangler is a more extreme example of this kind of behaviour.

So what can you do about this? Not much really, other than walk away from your teammates so their larger-than-reasonable invisible wall won't interfere.

Since making this educated guess of an answer, I have found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VflewO6lSI8) that proves it correct.

Comment: Easier said than done, especially if said teammate is a *cloaked Spy*.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "The Wrangler is a more extreme example"? I don't main engie so I don't often use the Wrangler. What happens?

Comment: If you and your sentry are standing in completely different spots, you can sometimes have a really hard time hitting anything with the Wrangler if your line of sight to a target is free but the sentry's is not.